# Prevent data insertion in N:M relational table when the inserted row doesn't have referential integrity with another field

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

**EDIT**

Even though the suggested "duplicate" led me to the correct answer, my question is still a bit different. I want to explain the difference:

I would like a generic utility that doesn't have hard-coded tables in it. The answer in the duplicate has hard-coded tables; however, it can be modified to work. I answered this question using a modified version of the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64044805/6846692). Mine is more generic and also uses the language `plpgsql`.

**Answer**

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION organization_check(l_id uuid, r_id uuid, l_tbl regclass, r_tbl regclass)
RETURNS boolean AS $$
    DECLARE is_valid boolean;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT count(*) = 1 FROM %1$I r JOIN %2$I l ON l.organization_id = r.organization_id
                    WHERE l.id = %3$L AND r.id = %4$L;', r_tbl, l_tbl, l_id, r_id) INTO is_valid;

    RETURN is_valid;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**Original**

I think I'm close to solving this but I can't quite get there 100%.. hoping there is a sql wizard on here that can help me get this through the finish line.

Here is my scenario:
I have a hierarchy of data:

- Organization

  - Contact
  - Location
  - Contact_Location (many to many)

I want to prevent any insertion of data into the `contact_location` table if the contact and location aren't of the same organization. I discovered this wasn't possible with a check constraint b/c it only has access to the current row's contact. Because of this I decided to try to implement it with a trigger/fn. I was able to get it working on a case by case basis, but I'd like to create a utility fn for this as it'll be a common situation. The utility function will generate a trigger for a table based on some arguments, this trigger will call a procedure that runs the validation logic for `organization_id`.

Below I've posted my code that I feel is very close. I'm getting an error back when trying to insert... here is what I ran and the output:

```
insert into contact_location (contact_id, location_id) values('873f8593-b989-4e1e-9d61-5a8524bde2c8', '82bd4c46-8fd7-499a-b3e3-872c925744e6');
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "new"
LINE 1: SELECT organization_id from contact WHERE id = NEW.contact_i...
                                                       ^
QUERY:  SELECT organization_id from contact WHERE id = NEW.contact_id;
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function check_organization_id_fn() line 12 at EXECUTE
```

Here is the current state of the function and trigger:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION verify_same_organization(
    l_tbl regclass,
    r_tbl regclass
) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('CREATE TRIGGER check_organization_id BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON %1$s_%2$s
                    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_organization_id_fn(%1$s, %2$s)', l_tbl, r_tbl);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_organization_id_fn() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE 
    l_org_id UUID;
    r_org_id UUID;

    l_tbl TEXT;
    r_tbl TEXT;        
BEGIN
    l_tbl := TG_ARGV[0];
    r_tbl := TG_ARGV[1];

    EXECUTE format('SELECT organization_id from %1$I WHERE id = NEW.%1$s_id;', l_tbl) INTO l_org_id;
    EXECUTE format('SELECT organization_id from %1$I WHERE id = NEW.%1$s_id;', r_tbl) INTO r_org_id;

    IF (l_org_id = r_org_id) THEN
        RETURN NEW; -- Allow insert or update
    ELSE
        RETURN NULL; -- Ignore insert or update if the left and right aren't a part of the same organization
    END IF; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TABLE contact_location (
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    contact_id UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES contact (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    location_id UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES location (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX contact_location_idx ON contact_location (contact_id, location_id);

SELECT verify_same_organization('contact', 'location');
```